# Iterating through elements returned by jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have some HTML that's structured more or less like which I want to be able to filter though by row.

```
<div class="parentElement">
   <div class="rowInput">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <input type="text" value="demo" />
   </div>

   <div class="rowInput">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <input type="text" value="demo" />
      <select> 
         <option>Value 1</option>
         <option>Value 2</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to get the two rows I need with

```
var row = $('.rowInput');

0: div.row.inputRow
1: div.row.inputRow
```

However I'm having issues with going through these rows and further and pulling out any information. I've tried a few different methods of looping through the rows however the best I've been able to do is traversing the property list of the elements. What want to do however is go through each element of the div.row.inputRow and pull out the information based on element type so I can store the information by row.

Edit: I was able to get what I wanted with the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log(rows[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < rows[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
            console.log(rows[i].childNodes[j]);
    }
}
```

However I'm getting errors whenever I try to use the jQuery '.is()' on the child nodes I'm returning

```
Uncaught TypeError: rows[i].childNodes[j].is is not a function
```

Basically what I'm going for in the end is returning each element with '.inputRow' so I can filter out the input of each row and either store it or discard it based on if the checkbox is selected. The main reason I'm going this route is I couldn't get the input I needed by row with both a 'select' and ':input' selector.

Comment: You'd have better to explain a little more your expected behaviour, not clear imho

Comment: @A.Wolff You're right, I added a bit more information at the bottom.

Comment: Still not clear but maybe this could help you: `$('.rowInput').has(':checkbox:checked').find(':input:not(:checkbox)')`  See e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/72of98d1/

Comment: The code you have posted is OK: https://jsfiddle.net/z72sqvon/2/ and it's not the code that has caused the error: `childNodes[j].is is not a function` - the `childNodes[j].is()` was probably the problem, because it's a HTML node reference, not a jQuery object, and doesn't have `.is` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct except for the way to get childerens try the following:

```
var rows = $('.rowInput');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  console.log(rows[i]);
  for (var j = 0; j < $(rows[i]).children().length; j++) {
    console.log( $(rows[i]).children()[j]);
  }
}
```

check it here:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z72sqvon/)

Comment: You can use `rows[i].children` without wrapping it in a jQuery object: https://jsfiddle.net/z72sqvon/1/

Comment: Yes, but in this case you are using javascript children not jquery one, and in case you want to get a value for example you will have to cast as jQuery not dom if you want to use .val() not val 
console.log( rows[i].children[j].value);
console.log( $(rows[i].children[j]).val());  so both work but just be carful which one to use.

Answer (score 2):

Try `each()` function:

```
$('.rowInput').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var checkbox = $this.find('input[type=checkbox]');
   var text = $this.find('input[type=text]');
});
```

The `$(this)` refers to each `.rowInput` element.